# JavaScript <form> validation

Tags: javascript, html

How do you validate a form when you use a link to submit it (not the submit button?)

This is what I use to submit form:

```
<a href='javascript:document.forms["send"].submit()'>Send</a>
```

But how do you check the text area inside the form and submit only if it's not empty?

Comment: Why are you using an A element instead of a submit button anyway?

Answer (score 3):

The onSubmit event still fires whether the form is submitted with a submit button or JavaScript. So monitoring the form's submit event should be all you need to do:

First, give yout form an ID for easy access. I'll use "myForm" in my example:

```
document.getElementById('myForm').onSubmit = function() {
    // validate textarea
    // return false on bad data
    // return true if ok
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Usually validation functions are attached to the onsubmit listener of the form and return `false` if the form should not submit, e.g.

```
<form ... onsubmit="return validate(this);" ...>
```

And the validate function is something like:

```
function validate(form) {
  var valid = true;
  var elements = form.elements;

  for (var i=0, iLen=elements.length; i<iLen; i++) {
    // validate elements[i]
    // if any invalid, set valid to false
  }
  return validl;    
}
```